# Associate an image with a category?

Tags: categories, images

Is it possible to associate an image with a category in Wordpress? I'm outputting a list of all categories and would like to feature an image alongside each category name.

Comment: do some google search for wordpress plugin, you'll find one

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to know how to achieve this directly, as I'd rather not use a plugin.